# Inserting text into textarea with javascript for google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, textarea

I am trying to extend the functionality of an existing google chrome extension.  Using the Wrike google chrome extension, my goal is to add a button (or buttons) which will add some text to the description field (a textarea).  The desired effect will be that if a user clicks an "Add Template" button, the code/text will be inserted into the textarea with id="description" which is native to the Wrike chrome extension.  Below you will find some of the code that I have been working with.

Here is the description part of the form.  Located in createTask.html

```
<div class="main-description main-row">
    <textarea placeholder="Click to add description" id="description" class="main-description-text"></textarea>
</div>
```

This is the button that I created which will initiate adding the text to the textarea:

```
<span class="btn m-green btn-addtemp" id="link">Add Template</span>
```

Within template.js (which is properly linked to as an external .js file within createTask.html:

```
function insertText(text) {
    document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = text;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var link = document.getElementById('link');
    link.addEventListener('click', function() {
        insertText('Sample text here');
    });
});
```

I can get this code to insert the 'Sample text here' into a div with an ID, but cannot get it to insert into the textarea with id=description.  Any help would be greatly appreciated and I am more than happy to provide more detailed information if necessary.  Thanks!

Comment: In reference to this question, does anyone have any possible solutions for being able to add formatted text to a textarea, or a different workaround for this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with element.value:

```
function insertText(text) {
    document.getElementById("description").value= text;
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly.  Thanks!  I knew it was something easy I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

To insert into textarea, use   value  properties :

```
function insertText(text) {
    document.getElementById("description").value= text;
}
```

instead of

```
function insertText(text) {
    document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"which will add some HTML tables and text to the description field (a textarea). ", this is not posible, textareas can not contain html.