# Adding Text To Text Area Using JavaScript In Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Can anyone please explain how i can set per-defined text into a particular text area of the external page(not the page that i have created)?

[Inserting text into textarea with javascript for google chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346956/inserting-text-into-textarea-with-javascript-for-google-chrome-extension)

I have also tried it but it is now working.

Please help!!

Comment: What do you have so far and what does it do instead?

Comment: See [Chrome extension: enter data into a custom-handled input field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849)